# Is "to do as little as" correct in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, tense, grammaticality

> And if someone was **to do as little as** touch a single hair on his sister’s head, he would hunt him down and seek vengeance even if it will take him a lifetime.

Is the sentence correct ?

I'm unsure of the sentence structure and the tenses that are used.

Comment: Can you [edit] to give more details on why you think it might be incorrect?

Comment: I'm really glad you found my answer helpful, but you might want to wait a while before selecting an answer. This post on meta explains some reasons why: http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1307/9161

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 'If someone [were](https://www.grammarly.com/handbook/sentences/conditional-sentences/6/conditional-sentences-was-instead-of-were-in-the-u/) to [so much as](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/so+much+as) touch a single hair...' is how I would say it.

We use 'were' instead of 'was' when we're talking about things we're imagining might happen (or things we wish for, like 'If I were a rich man') even when the subject is singular. As [Grammar Girl explains](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/subjunctive-verbs?page=1), we use the subjunctive when we're talking about something that isn't true. Often (but not always) clauses that start with "if" are expressing a wish or something contrary to fact, so 'if' is a clue that we might need the subjunctive form.

"So much as" is an idiom that is a very emphatic "even". For example,

> "I didn't {so much as/even} blink at him and he started yelling at me for being disrespectful."

You could use "even" there but I feel that "so much as" is a little bit stronger.